# Suppose that $n(r)$ denotes the number of integer points on a circle of radius$>1$...

Tags: inequality, analytic-geometry

Suppose that $n(r)$ denotes the number of points with integer co-ordinates on a circle of radius $r>1$.

Prove that, $n(r)<2\pi r^{2/3}$

I could not get much help from a similar question, though a much weaker inequality $n(r)<6{\pi^{1/3} r^{2/3}}$ from Iranian Mathematical Olympiad 1999.

Comment: Please check what you have presented.  I'm guessing that the Iranian answer is misrepresented, simply because as it stands, the $6$ and $3$ would have been simplified.

Comment: @doc.that should be okay now i guess.was a typo.

Comment: This is equivalent to bounding the number of integers solutipns to the equation $x^2+y^2 = r^2$.  Moreover, $x=r\cos{\theta}$ and $y=\sin{\theta}$, so it's saying something about the trig functions.

Comment: @doc.there is no upper bound,if something then a lower one.

Comment: I'm saying you want to establish an upper bound.

Comment: @doc.yes, but to me, there isn't any such scope, and also if I establish an upper bound, the problem doesn't reduce to a simple one.

Comment: I believe I can show that two such points on the circle must be at a distance apart of at least $r\sqrt{2}$.  That should help.

Comment: @Doc.But it is not about distance but the number of points. So,can you please tell me how can I utilise that to be of my help?

Comment: First I'm not 100% sure of my result.  I would have to check it carefully.  But can't you see how to use this information?  Think of the points on the circle.  They can only be so close thogether.  Count the maximum number of points possible.  That would give an upper bound. Meanwhile I'll check my work.

Comment: Well, here's a sketch of how to proceed.  Imagine that $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are two points on $x^2+y^2=r^2$, and compute the square of the distance $\Delta$ between them.  You should get

Comment: Well, here's a sketch of how to proceed.  Imagine that $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are two points on $x^2+y^2=r^2$, and compute the square of the distance $\Delta$ between them.  You should get $\Delta^2=2r^2-2(ac+bd)$. Now let $\theta$ be the angle between these two points.  Clearly $n_r \theta \le 2\pi$.  Now note that the triangle formed by the origin and the points $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ is isoceles.  Use the law of cosines to compute in another way the distance $\Delta$.  Now compare the two measurements of $\Delta$ and use the inequality $n_r\le \frac{2\pi}{\theta}$.

Comment: Oops.  Critical error.  Change $n_r\theta \le 2\pi$ to $n_r\theta \le 2\pi r$ in two places in my last comment.

Comment: I'm sorry. It was right in the first place.  Any luck?

Comment: nothing much yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $r>1$ and $2\pi>6$, we may assume $n\ge7$

Label the $n$ lattice points $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_n$.The (counterclockwise)arcs $P_1P_3,P_2P_4,\ldots,P_nP_2$ cover the circle twice so they sum upto $4\pi$. Therefore, one of them, say arc $P_1P_3$ measures at most $\frac{4\pi}{n}$.

Consider the triangle $P_1P_2P_3$ which is inscribed in an arc of measure $\frac{4\pi}{n}$. Because $n\ge7$,the arc is less than a quarter of the circle. The area of $P_1P_2P_3$ will be maximized if $P_1$ and $P_3$ are the endpoints and $P_2$ is the midpoint of the arc.In that case,

$\Delta(P_1P_2P_3)=\dfrac{abc}{4r}=\dfrac{2r\sin\frac{\pi}{n}2r\sin\frac{\pi}{n}2r\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}}{4r}\le\dfrac{2r\frac{\pi}{n}2r\frac{\pi}{n}2r\frac{2\pi}{n}}{4r}=\dfrac{4r^2\pi^3}{n^3}$

And in general, the area of $P_1P_2P_3$ cannot exceed $\dfrac{4r^2\pi^3}{n^3}$.On the other hand, if the co-ordinates of the point $P_1,P_2,P_3$ are respectively $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3)$ then $\Delta(P_1P_2P_3)=\dfrac12|x_1y_2-x_2y_1+x_2y_3-x_3y_2+x_3y_1-x_1y_3|$
Because the co-ordinates of the points are integers, the area cannot be less than $\dfrac12$.

We obtain the inequality $\dfrac12\le\dfrac{4r^2\pi^3}{n^3}$
Which proves $2\pi r^{2/3}\ge n$

Answer (score 0):

There is a well-known result (more-or-less equivalent to the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is an euclidean domain) that states that the number of $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $x^2+y^2=n$, say $r_2(n)$, is equal to four times a multiplicative function of $n$, for instance:
$$ r_2(n) = 4\cdot(\chi_4*1)(n) = 4\cdot(d_1(n)-d_3(n)), $$
where
$$d_1(n)=|\{d\in\mathbb{N}: d|n, d\equiv 1\!\!\!\pmod{4}\}|,$$
$$d_3(n)=|\{d\in\mathbb{N}: d|n, d\equiv 3\!\!\!\pmod{4}\}|.$$
So the number of integer points on the circle $x^2+y^2=n^2$ is bounded by:
$$ r_2(n) \leq 4\cdot\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! \prod_{\substack{p|n\\p\equiv 1\!\!\pmod{\!\!4}}}\!\!\!\!\!(1+2\,\nu_p(n))\leq 4\cdot d(n^2),$$
where $\nu_p(n)$ is the maximum $h\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p^h|n$, and equality is attained when all the prime divisors of $n$ belong to the arithmetic progression $4k+1$. Following the spirit of [https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/the-divisor-bound/[1](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/the-divisor-bound/), consider now that for every prime $p\geq 23>e^3$ and every $\alpha\geq  0$
$$\frac{2\alpha+1}{p^{2\alpha/3}}\leq 1$$
holds in virtue of the Bernoulli inequality, while:
$$\frac{2\alpha+1}{5^{2\alpha/3}}\leq\frac{3}{5^{2/3}},\qquad \frac{2\alpha+1}{13^{2\alpha/3}}\leq 1,\qquad \frac{2\alpha+1}{17^{2\alpha/3}}\leq 1$$
hold for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$. This trivially gives:
$$ r_{2}(n)\leq \frac{12}{5^{2/3}} n^{2/3} < \frac{37}{9} n^{2/3}, $$
or
$$ n(r) < \left(4+\frac{1}{9}\right) r^{2/3} $$
in your notation.